# Blue Lines from Annotations not in any object

Tags: select, annotation

I am just starting to use annotation grease pencil. I created one set successfully, then tried to create another one. I selected draw cursor, then proceeded to draw the the annotation curves (The blue lines you see). But when i went to change the geometry cross section nothing happened., it just went blue.

So I delete the curve to start again, and the blue lines were still there. I cannot select them, when I hide all items they are still there. It is very strange.

Anyone know what might be the problem here?

[image: Blue Lines]

Comment: it looks like annotations, not bezier curves, try to press D + right click to erase, or select the annotation tool in the tool panel (T, on the right of the 3D view) and press Ctrl

Comment: Thank you very much. I don't know how i did that instead of drawing the curves.

Comment: It must be because when you're in Edit mode, you've confused the annotation tool with the draw tool

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are not bezier curves, these are annotations. Once in *Edit* mode you must have confused the *Annotate* tool with the *Draw* tool:

[image]

To erase the annotations, press <kbd>D</kbd> + right click, or select the Annotate tool and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>

Comment: That is exactly what i did.